# Authorization Header to Azure Tables fails with 403 "Authoization header malformed"

Tags: azure, delphi, azure-table-storage

I pieced together code to authorize to Microsoft Azure for a Storage Account Table operation.

```
function TAzureStorageAPI.GetAuthHeader(RequestMethod,Ressource,Time:UTF8String): String;

Var
  KeyBytes:TBytes;
  DataBytes:TBytes;
  TimeString,
  StringtoSign:UTF8String;

begin
  StringtoSign:=Uppercase(RequestMethod)+LF+                                  //RequestMethod
                ''+LF+                                                        //contentMD5
                'application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1'+LF+                                //contentType
                TimeString+LF+                                                //requestDate
                Ressource;                                                    //Ressource
  keyBytes:=TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(FAccessKey);
  dataBytes:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
  result:= (TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(dataBytes, keyBytes)));
end;

function TAzureStorageAPI.Insert(PartitionKey,RowKey:String; Data:tlkJSONObject):tlkJSONObject;

Var
  PostHeaders:TStringlist;
  Time:TDateTime;
  TimeString:String;

begin
  Socket.Request.Accept:='application/json;odata=minimalmetadata';
  PostHeaders:=TStringlist.Create;
  PostHeaders.Add('x-ms-version:2019-07-07');
  Time:=TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  TimeString:=FormatDateTime('ddd, dd mmm yyyy hh:nn:ss',Time)+' UTC';
  PostHeaders.Add('Date:'+TimeString);
  PostHeaders.Add('MaxDataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx');
  PostHeaders.Add('DataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx');
  PostHeaders.Add('Authorization:SharedKey '+FStorageAccount+':'+GetAuthHeader('post','/'+FStorageAccount+'/'+FTable,TimeString));
  Host:=FStorageAccount+'.table.core.windows.net';
  Data.Add('PartitionKey',PartitionKey);
  Data.add('RowKey',RowKey);
  result:=WebPostData('/'+FTable,PostHeaders,Data)as tlkJSONObject;
  PostHeaders.Free;
end;
```

- StorageAccount is the name I get from the SharedKey-Options
- Table is the name of the ressource from the Table Service
- and AccessKey is Key1 from the SharedKey-Options

The StringToSign is

```
'POST'#$A#$A'application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1'#$A'Mo, 27 Apr 2020 18:02:33 UTC'#$A'/smartflatlog/Log'
```

I am not using any access policy on the resource.

After fixing a bug in the passing of the headers I see the following transmit on the wire:

```
Ges 27.04.2020 20:02:48: POST /Log HTTP/1.1<EOL>Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1<EOL>Content-Length: 104<EOL>x-ms-version: 2019-07-07<EOL>Date: Mo, 27 Apr 2020 18:02:33 UTC<EOL>MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx<EOL>DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx<EOL>Authorization: SharedKey smartflatlog:KVtJ*********************************A5zOME=<EOL>Host: smartflatlog.table.core.windows.net<EOL>Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata<EOL>User-Agent: Demo<EOL><EOL>
Ges 27.04.2020 20:02:48: {"Level":"Debug","LogText":"something to note","Application":"Demo","PartitionKey":"Demo","RowKey":"13"}
Erh 27.04.2020 20:02:48: HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.<EOL>Content-Length: 299<EOL>Content-Type: application/json<EOL>Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0<EOL>x-ms-request-id: 86f7fd8d-2002-0021-63be-1c5d47000000<EOL>x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed<EOL>Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 18:02:49 GMT<EOL><EOL>{"odata.error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:86f7fd8d-2002-0021-63be-1c5d47000000\nTime:2020-04-27T18:02:49.6860540Z"}}}
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to insert an entity in the table. Can you trace the request/response through Fiddler? That should give you more details about the error.

Comment: ah, there was a bug deep down in the send-socket method, failing to add the headers :-(
Thx for the hint, now I get "authorization header invalid", but I will open a new post for this.

Comment: No need to open a new question :). Just update the title of the question and provide the most current code.

Comment: Again, please check the Fiddler response. Usually it should tell you the data used by the Storage Service to calculate `StringtoSign`. Please include that as well in your question.

Comment: Also, please include your `StringtoSign` variable's value.

Comment: "StringToSign" is "'POST'#$A#$A'application/json'#$A'2020-04-27T17:56:27.043+02:00'#$A'/smartflatlog/Log''"

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's `#$A` in your `StringToSign`? It should be `\n`. Also your date format is wrong. It should be `Mon, 27 Apr 2020 17:56:27 GMT`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key.

Comment: I'll check on the date (how to get into this format in Delphi), but the #$A is LineFeed (which is "/n" I guess)

Comment: Ahh...I didn't know about #$A. Please check the date. Most likely that's the culprit :). You will also need to include the `Date` request header as well.

Comment: 'POST'#$A#$A'application/json'#$A'Mo, 27 Apr 2020 16:35:43 GMT'#$A'/smartflatlog/Log'

no change :-/

Comment: Please either include `Content-Type` header in your request with `application/json` as value or replace `application/json` in your StringToSign with empty string.

Comment: Do you mean either or? Currently it's in the POST Header AND in the "StringToSign"...

Comment: Yes. Either it should be present in both places or not present at all. Currently it is there in your `StringToSign` but not in request headers.

Comment: it is...
POST /Log HTTP/1.1<EOL>Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1<EOL>

Comment: In that case, it should be the same in `StringToSign` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212634/discussion-between-wolfgang-bures-and-gaurav-mantri).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an entity with Sharekey auth, the `stringtosign` should be like

```
StringToSign = VERB + "\n" +
               Content-MD5 + "\n" +
               Content-Type + "\n" +  
               Date + "\n" +  
               CanonicalizedResource;
```

For example

```
 RequestMethod:= 'GET';

  dateInRfc1123Format:= TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  TheDate:= formatdatetime('ddd, dd mmm yyyy hh:nn:ss "GMT"',dateInRfc1123Format);
  contentType:='application/json;odata=nometadata'
canonicalizedResource:= "/yourAccount/yourTable"
 stringToSign:= format('%s\n'+ // request method

                        '\n' + // content md5
                        '%s\n' + // content type
                        '%s\n' + // date
                        '%s', // canonicalized ResourceL,
                        [RequestMethod,
                        contentType,
                        TheDate,
                        canonicalizedResource]);
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/payload-format-for-table-service-operations)

Comment: But that is exactly what I am doing! But you are not using the content-type, but the accepted type in the stingtosign....

Comment: @WolfgangBuresw Regarding the content-type, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity

Comment: I know these articles quite well by now. :-)
What you are showing in the code above, is a bit different than how I read it. You use the ACCEPT header in the StringtoSign instead of the CONTENT-TYPE.
I did test your approach, without luck I must say.

Comment: @WolfgangBures please try to do not provide the content type value in StringtoSign

Comment: So this didnt work neither with seperator being CRLF, LF, or "\n".

StringtoSign:=Uppercase(RequestMethod)+Separator+      //RequestMethod
                ''+Separator+                                                        //contentMD5
                ''+Separator+                                                   //contentType
                Time+Separator+                                                //requestDate
                Ressource;                                                    //Ressource

Comment: @WolfgangBuresw According to the document as above, we need to use `HMAC-SHA256` to sign. Regarding how to implement it, please refer to https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/

Comment: I was using HMAC-SHA256 before, but I have also tried it with the indy-version of your link. No luck :-(